# iPhone with broken home button is stuck on black screen after jailbreaking

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 3Gs and recently noticed that the home button doesn't work anymore. I used AssistiveTouch.

Now I want to jailbreak my iPhone, but it's gone wrong: the device is stuck on a black screen after jailbreaking, iTunes doesn't recognise my iPhone and my home button doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Let the iphone discharge.
Then connect it to your computer.
If iTunes recognize it, try to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't restore the device to factory settings after connecting it to iTunes, I'm afraid the best you can do is take it to a authorized Apple service center and get it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I would reccomend a vist to authorised apple service centre.Better leave it to the professionals.

Comment: I know, but i'm in Belgium, and there aren't so many of these stores here. I searched it on Google and found a program called RecBoot, but it shoeldn't work on 64 bit computers, and i have one... Do you think it's gonna work if i run a 32 bit version of windows in virtual machine and then try recboot? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.